# Cannot add additionalData to .scss files in my Vue project

Tags: vue.js, sass, vuejs3

I'm coding with Vue and SCSS. For some reason, I want to use an environment variable in a .scss file. There is much discussion about [how to use an environment variable in an SCSS block in a .vue file](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/19042#discussioncomment-126507). But it will not work with a .scss file. Could anyone tell me how to do that?

[Here](https://github.com/Nathan7139/vue-sass-loader-issue) is a minimal reproducible example of my question. You can use `npm install` for install and use `npm run serve` to testing.

In file `src/App.vue`, I use `$test` to set color and it work fine.
In file `src/style.scss`, if I use `$test`, it will indicate that `$test` is an undefined variable.

```scss
div {
  font-size: 100px;

  // error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss
  
  //   Syntax Error: SassError: Undefined variable.
  //    ╷
  // 14 │   @if $test == 'a' {
  //    │       ^^^^^
  //    ╵
  //   src/style.scss 14:7  @use
  //   src/App.vue 1:1      root stylesheet

  @if $test == 'a' {
    background-color: blue;
  } @else if $test == 'apple' {
    background-color: green;
  } @else {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

So additionalData work for .vue file but not .scss fils. I wonder is there a simple way to use an environment variable in a .scss file?

Comment: I bet it's out of the question to simply use your scss as an asset and instead of using it directly just importing it into the layout file style tag?

Answer (score 0):

In your scss file, you can call `.env` variables with the `env()` function. e.g.

```scss
// defining the variable
$test: env(VUE_APP_TEST);

// your styles
div {
  font-size: 100px;

  @if $test == "a" {
    background-color: blue;
  } @else if $test == "apple" {
    background-color: green;
  } @else {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

**Edit**: Remember to restart your server after editing your environment variables.

Comment: I try and the value of $test is `'env(VUE_APP_TEST)'`, it appears that the env function is not functioning correctly. Could you provide more details about your answer?

Comment: I tested it on your code and it was working fine, make sure whenever you change the environment variables, you restart the server.

Comment: @Nathan did you restart the server after changing env vars?

Comment: Yes, I restart server. The value of $test always is  `'env(VUE_APP_TEST)'`.